# Clarification on Author when creating a branch in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-branch

I created a branch from the master branch in Azure Devops, but the Author name and date, were the same as the master branch, shouldn't the author name be my name?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A branch in Git is just a reference to a particular commit. It contains no information about an author. The author information is coming from the commit the branch currently refers to.

When you created the new branch `MailMergeService`, it was a reference to the same commit as `master` was referring to, so it is showing the same author information.

If you create a new commit for the `MailMergeService` branch, the author will be taken from that commit, which can then be different from the author that is shown for `master`.